# Split line in Python 2.7

Tags: python, split, python-2.x

I want to split line with Python `W03*17*65.68*KG*0.2891*CR*1*1N` and then capture 
Value qty as 17
Value kg as 65,68

Tried with split

```
myarray = Split(strSearchString, "*")
a = myarray(0)
b = myarray(1)
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6):

[`split`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) is a method of the string itself, and you can access elements of a list with `[42]`, not the method call `(42)`[<sup>doc</sup>](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists). Try:

```
s = 'W03*17*65.68*KG*0.2891*CR*1*1N'
lst = s.split('*')
qty = lst[1]
weight = lst[2]
weight_unit = lst[3]
```

You may also be interested in tuple unpacking:

```
s = 'W03*17*65.68*KG*0.2891*CR*1*1N'
_,qty,weight,weight_unit,_,_,_,_ = s.split('*')
```

You can even use a [slice](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings):

```
s = 'W03*17*65.68*KG*0.2891*CR*1*1N'
qty,weight,weight_unit = s.split('*')[1:4]
```

Comment: I think `qty,weight,weight_unit = s.split('*')[1:4]` looks better.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thanks, added that as well. I presumed that the next version will most likely have to deal with the extra values as well ;)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary another possible using slicing is: `qty, weight, weight_unit, rest = s.split('*', 4)[1:])` and I suppose in 3.x you could `qty, weight, weight_unit, *rest = s.split('*')[1:]`

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> s = "W03*17*65.68*KG*0.2891*CR*1*1N"
>>> lst = s.split("*")
>>> lst[1]
'17'
>>> lst[2]
'65.68'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke `split` method on a certain string to split it. Just using `Split(my_str, "x")` won't work: -

```
>>> my_str = "Python W03*17*65.68*KG*0.2891*CR*1*1N"
>>> tokens = my_str.split('*')
>>> tokens
['Python W03', '17', '65.68', 'KG', '0.2891', 'CR', '1', '1N']
>>> tokens[1]
'17'
>>> tokens[2]
'65.68'
```

Comment: what's the use of `r` in `split()` ?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary.. Actually it is not needed. just tested it. I thought it to be a `raw string`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
myarray = string.split(strSearchString, "*")
qty = myarray[1]
kb = myarray[2]
```

Comment: The use of the `string` module is deprecated. Use string methods instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
 >>>s ="W03*17*65.68*KG*0.2891*CR*1*1N"

 >>>my_string=s.split("*")[1] 

>>> my_string
   '17'

>>> my_string=s.split("*")[2] 

>>> my_string
 '65'
```

> > > 

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to capture Value qty as 17 Value kg as 65.68, 
one way to solve it is using dictionary after splitting strings.

```
>>> s = 'W03*17*65.68*KG*0.2891*CR*1*1N'
>>> s.split('*')
['W03', '17', '65.68', 'KG', '0.2891', 'CR', '1', '1N']
>>> t = s.split('*')
>>> dict(qty=t[1],kg=t[2])
{'kg': '65.68', 'qty': '17'}
```

Hope it helps.